# In .htaccess is HTTP_COOKIE treated as a single string?

Tags: .htaccess, cookies

I'm wanting to block access to a folder if a cookie is not set to a certain value.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !some-cookie-name=some-cookie-value [NC]
RewriteRule .* /some-sort-of-error/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

It seems to take the cookie name and value and treat it as a string `cookie-name=cookie-value`. It seems to only check if this string *contains* `cookie-name=cookie-value` rather than *equal it*.

So in the above if the cookie name was `foo-some-cookie-name` and/or the value is `some-cookie-value-foo` access to the folder is granted.

Is this normal behaviour or is there any way to get it to match exactly? Is `HTTP_COOKIE` a concatenation of the entire cookie array as a single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to get it to match exactly

Sure you can use this enhanced regex to make sure no wanted text is matched:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|\s)some-cookie-name=some-cookie-value(;|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /some-sort-of-error/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Multiple cookies are separated by a semi colon and a space.

Comment: Thanks, what does (^|\s) and (;|$) do exactly?

Comment: That is regex. `(^|\s)` means match line start or space. `(;|$)` means match `;` or line end.

Comment: Good explanation. So I infer form tat that HTTP_COOKIE is a string with each cookie on its own line, yes?

Comment: Not on separate lines but multiple cookies are separated by a semi colon and a space.

Comment: Just negation will do that (see updated answer with `!` in condition)